# Django ValueError at /imagetarget/ Cannot assign "<SimpleLazyObject: <User: dip7777>>":

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Error message

```py
Cannot assign "<SimpleLazyObject: <User: dip7777>>": "ImageTarget.uploaderclient" must be a "UploaderClient" instance.
```

I'm working on Python 3.4.3 and Django 1.8 and using Django Rest Framework 3.
I'm using the DRF browsable API for testing.

What I'm trying to do is to attach the currently logged in user to the file that he uploads.

Whenever I try to do a POST and upload a file with a logged in user, it throws up the above error.

I have a couple of `UploaderClient` created and the user `dip7777` is one such user tied to a UploaderClient. I have logged in using that user.

What I am able to accomplish with the current code is edit the currently uploaded file ie. upload a new file in place of the current file using the `ImageTargetDetail` view. 
(I had uploaded a couple of files and tied them to `UploaderClients` using the admin interface)

What I want to do is upload a new file using the `ImageTargetList` view and not replace a preexisting one.
But the error shows up and I do not understand how to assign the current(logged in) `uploaderclient` instance to the `ImageTarget`'s `uploaderclient`

I have two models 1)UploaderClient

```py
class UploaderClient(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    company_name = models.CharField(_('company name'), max_length=100)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('uploaderclient')
        verbose_name_plural = _('uploaderclients')
    def __str__(self):
        return 'UploaderClient: {}'.format(self.user.username)
```

and 2) ImageTarget

```py
class ImageTarget(models.Model):
    uploaderclient = models.ForeignKey('authenticateclients.UploaderClient', related_name='imagetargets')
    targetName = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    imageWidth = models.IntegerField()
    targetFile = models.FileField(upload_to=get_upload_imagetargetfile_name)
```

in two different apps `authenticateclients` and `clientupload`

My serializers are:

```py
class UploaderClientSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    username = serializers.CharField(source='user.username')
    email = serializers.CharField(source='user.email', required=False, allow_null=True)
    password = serializers.CharField(source='user.password', write_only=True, required=False)
    date_joined = serializers.DateTimeField(source='user.date_joined', read_only=True)
    last_login = serializers.DateTimeField(source='user.last_login', read_only=True)
    company_name = serializers.CharField()
    imagetargets = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(many=True, view_name='imagetargetsdetail', read_only=True)
    url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name='uploaderclientsdetail')
    class Meta:
        model = UploaderClient
        fields = ('url', 'email', 'username', 'company_name', 'date_joined', 'last_login', 'password','imagetargets',)
        read_only_fields = ('user.date_joined', 'user.last_login',)
```

and

```py
class ImageTargetSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    uploaderclient = UploaderClientSerializer(read_only=True,required=False)
    targetFile = serializers.FileField(label='TargetFile')
    url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name='imagetargetsdetail')
    class Meta:
        model = ImageTarget
        fields = ('url','uploaderclient','targetName','imageWidth','targetFile',)
    def get_validation_exclusions(self):
        exclusions = super(ImageTargetSerializer, self).get_validation_exclusions()
        return exclusions + ['uploaderclient']
```

My views are

```py
class UploaderClientList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = UploaderClient.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UploaderClientSerializer
class UploaderClientDetail(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = UploaderClient.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UploaderClientSerializer
```

and

```py
class ImageTargetList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = ImageTarget.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ImageTargetSerializer
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        instance = serializer.save(uploaderclient=self.request.user)
        return super(ImageTargetList, self).perform_create(serializer)
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,IsOwnerOrNothing,)
class ImageTargetDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = ImageTarget.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ImageTargetSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,IsOwnerOrNothing,)
@api_view(('GET',))
def api_root(request, format=None):
    return Response({
        'uploaderclients': reverse('uploaderclients', request=request, format=format),
        'imagetargets': reverse('imagetargets', request=request, format=format),
    })
```

Comment: so which view causes the error?

Comment: I am trying to POST via the `ImageTargetList` view and this causes the error because I'm uploading something new. If I POST via the the `ImageTargetDetail` view, then I am replacing a preexisting file and I am able to do this currently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ImageTargetList.perform_create:

```
instance = serializer.save(uploaderclient=self.request.user)
```

However uploaderclient should not be a user.

Comment: How do I make `self.request.user` to return a `uploaderclient` object? It always returns `user`. I removed the following line `return super(ImageTargetList, self).perform_create(serializer)` and tried. Still throws the same error.

Comment: @rasalghul you should firstly search the uploaderclient related to the user, and pass the uploaderclient to the serializer.

Comment: and removing the super calling is no use, as it is not the source of error.